# Finding a common denominator when adding binomial coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

I'm working my way through Serge Lang's Basic Mathematics. I'm having some trouble with exercise 7d on page 40:

> Show that if $n$ is a positive integer at most equal to $m$, then
> $$
> \binom{m}{n} + \binom{m}{n - 1} = \binom{m + 1}{n}.
> $$

I understand that I need to show that the following is true, obtained by using the binomial coefficient formula:

$$
\frac{m!}{n!(m - n)!} + \frac{m!}{(n - 1)!(m - (n - 1))!} = \frac{(m + 1)!}{n!((m + 1) - n)!}
$$

When I add the two operands on the left side, I get the following:

$$
\frac{m!(n - 1)!(m - n + 1)! + m!n!(m - n)!}{n!(m - n)!(n - 1)!(m - n + 1)!}
$$

And then I'm not sure how to proceed further. There is a solution to the exercise in the book, which shows that the next step should be as follows:

$$
\frac{m!(m - n + 1) + m!n}{n!(m - n + 1)!}
$$

However I do not understand how adding $\frac{m!}{n!(m - n)!}$ and $\frac{m!}{(n - 1)!(m - (n - 1))!}$ results in the above.

Comment: Hint: $n! = n(n-1)!$ and $(m-(n-1))! = (m-(n-1))(m-n)!$.

Comment: @player3236 Thank you - that was the perfect hint! I managed to work it out now.